# take input of int and double but after that it can't take input for string..and directly give output..what is my mistake?

Tags: java, runtime-error

Below i gave you a program that take input of int and double but after that it can't take input for string..and directly give output..what is my mistake?

code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s = scan.nextLine();
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d =scan.nextDouble();
    

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the input your are typing in? What is the output you are getting?

Comment: "but after that it can't take input for string" - well yeah, the String is the FIRST thing you read.

Answer (score 0):

It's working perfectly. You need to first enter String value, then double and last int.
You need to enter in the sequence you have used the Scanner object.